# ¿Cuándo es correcto guardar datos numéricos en un variable string?

Tags: variables, pascal

Hace tiempo escuche por los pasillos de la universidad que las bases de datos trabajaban más rápido con las variables de tipo cadena entonces me surgió la siguiente pregunta:

¿Cuándo es correcto guardar datos numéricos  en un variable string?

Pensando un poco llegue a la siguiente conclusión
Cuando no se requiera hacer operaciones con números como lo pueden ser los números de teléfono, números de DNI o cualquier número de identificación pero no sé si con los lenguajes de programación trabajen igual y tampoco sé si lo que escuche sea cierto por ese motivo lo pregunto acá actualmente estoy trabajando con pascal

Comment: Usa un solo lenguaje en tu pregunta, las reglas en un lenguaje no necesariamente se va a cumplir en otras. Si usas varios lenguajes tu pregunta sera demasiado amplia haciendo dificil responder.

Comment: Sencillamente estas en lo correcto. Por otro lado tal vez te interesa el tamaño que ocupa en memoria, que puedes encontrar aquí: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_dato#Caracteres Pero con las tecnologías actuales, a menos que trabajes con equipos embebidos o con muy limitada memoria como un Arduino, dudo que esa diferencia tenga alguna importancia en un lenguaje de programación.

Comment: De todas maneras, puedes realizar pruebas a ver que pasa.

Comment: Las bases de datos no trabajan necesariamente más rápido con variables de tipo cadena. Los tipos numéricos suelen ser almacenados y procesados de manera más eficiente para muchas operaciones. Con las capacidades de computación actual, también es cierto que la diferencia muchas veces es tan pequeña, que se considera despreciable.

Comment: Sobre pascal, o cualquier otro lenguaje, el criterio al que has llegado parece bueno. Yo en general, almaceno los números como números, siempre y cuando realmente sea un número. Un _número de teléfono_, aunque se llame _número_, no es en realidad un tipo numérico, pues puede tener número de área, código de país, etc, Igual el _DNI_ que supongo tienen dígitos verificadores. En realidad estos no son números.

Comment: Pues salvo que des alguna razón para apoyar esa afirmación siento decir que no estoy de acuerdo con tu afirmación y creo que es un error. ¿Qué sentido tiene almacenar un dato numérico en un campo de tipo string? Ocupa más espacio, no es lógico, requiere operaciones de conversión, puede devolver un orden incorrecto, puede llevar a equivocaciones,...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta: Por lo general, nunca.

Digo "por lo general", porque dejando de lado casos concretos que pueden tener su lógica y habría que discutir uno a uno, lo normal y lo correcto es que para un tipo de datos se utilice una variable y un campo del tipo adecuado. Sea numérico, entero, cadena, booleano, caracter,...

Las razones para hecerlo así podrían ser:

- **Las operaciones a realizar** con el campo dependen del tipo de este: Por ejemplo, si intentas ordenar un campo cadena en el que has almacenado números el resultado será incorrecto. El número 20 es mayor que el 9, pero si están almacenados en un campo "cadena" en la Base de Datos obtendrás un orden incorrecto.
- **Conversiones Innecesarias**: Si almacenas un dato numérico en un campo de tipo "cadena", ya sea en la Base de Datos (consultas, stored procedures o funciones) o en tu programa, deberás convertir ese dato al tipo correcto en algún momento. Más de las que deberías hacer si el tipo de datos y el campo fueran coincidentes.
- **Facilitar la comprensión**: Ya sea porque tú debes revisar el código (o la estructura de la Base de Datos) o porque lo debe revisar otra persona a posteriori, uno espera encontrarse cosas "normales". Si yo veo un `nombre de campo` o `nombre de una variable` que representa un dato numérico, espero que el tipo sea coherente, no espero que alguien haya decidido cambiarlo por otro. Lo mismo es aplicable a un campo booleano que alguien haya decidido definir como `char` ("T" o "F") o un enumerado/tipificado que alguien haya decidido definir como cadena ("CASADO", "SOLTERO", "DIVORCIADO").
- **Por pura lógica**. De verdad que alguien definió varios tipos y los pensó para ser utilizados. Cada uno tiene sus particularidades y sus propiedades. No hagamos inventos...

Responsdiendo al primer comentario de tu explicación: Falso.

Por lo general, las Bases de Datos **NO** trabajan más rápido con campos de tipo cadena que con campos de tipo numérico. Basta con que pruebes a realizar las operaciones básicas sobre una lista de datos numéricos o sobre una lista de datos de tipo cadena (en cualquier lenguaje). `Ordenar` una lista de números frente a una lista de cadenas, `Buscar` en una lista de números o buscar en una lista de cadenas, `Filtrar` en una lista de números o una lista de cadenas.

Las propias Bases de Datos te dan la respuesta. Busca si es preferible en un campo clave utilizar `INT` (numérico) o `VARCHAR` (cadena). La respuesta a esa pregunta contesta esa afirmación.

Comment: No voy a editar, porque es una letra, pero creo que te refieres a comprensión, de comprender, en lugar de compresión, de comprimir.

Comment: @Jose Manuel Morales  Es correcta tu apreciación. Modifico la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: "Las propias Bases de Datos te dan la respuesta. Busca si es preferible en un campo clave utilizar INT (numérico) o VARCHAR (cadena). La respuesta a esa pregunta contesta esa afirmación." Vos podes asegurar que esto es por velocidad? o es simplemente porque en un abecedario el limite es mas corto, y es mas dificil saber el orden? Quien dijo que es mas lento una cadena que un numero? los dos se guardan en arboles binarios (o lo que use la db) a la hora de guardar. Y se puede optimizar para uno u otro. Por el resto, tu respuesta estaria bien.

Comment: @gbianchi   
"Vos podes asegurar que esto es por velocidad?"=> Cualquier operación con datos numéricos es más rápìda que la misma operación con esos mismos datos almacenados como cadenas (y basta con que lo pruebes).
"o es simplemente porque en un abecedario el limite es mas corto," => Al contrario el abecedario tiene más elementos que cifras sólo numéricas.
"y es mas dificil saber el orden?" => Esa es una de las operaciones que te comento en el punto primero que es más rápida con números que con cadenas (y no es una operación que se use poco).

Answer (score 0):

Si lo analizamos el uso de memoria un número representado por un entero (int) ocupa 4 byte mientras que cada carácter ocupa 1 byte.

Entonces si guardas un número inferior a 2147483647 ocuparas 4 byte.

pero para representar ese mismo número con caracteres vas a necesitar 10 bytes.

Aunque no vayas a aplicar operaciones matemáticas hay puedes encontrar la diferencia entre necesitar 4gb o necesitar 10 gb de ram para un programa.